# Attempted import error: '../../config/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Config')

Tags: reactjs, config

I'm getting this error:

> Attempted import error: '../../config/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Config')

When I run this file `common.js`:

```
import React, {Component,PropTypes} from 'react'
import {Input,DateTime,Tags,Radio,CheckBox,TextArea,Select,Image,HTML,File,Color,Relation,Icons,GoogleMap} from './index'
import Config from   '../../config/app';
import Common from '../../
```

Comment: Show us how you're exporting `Config`

Comment: Explain your question in more brief with necessary code

Answer (score 0):

I would check your Config component to make sure it's properly exported, it can also cause this issue if there is missing brackets etc in that Config file.

It would help if you showed the Config file as well.

Comment: import firebaseConfig from './firebase_config'

//FireBase - //Since version 6.0.0 , config is fetched from firebase_config.js - for easier setup
exports.firebaseConfig = firebaseConfig.config;

//App setup
exports.adminConfig={
  "appName": "React app builder",
  "slogan":"make mobile apps.",
  "design":{
    "sidebarBg":"sidebar-2.jpg", //sidebar-1, sidebar-2, sidebar-3
    "dataActiveColor":"rose", //"purple | blue | green | orange | red | rose"
    "dataBackgroundColor":"black", // "white | black"
  },
  "showItemIDs":false,
  "allowedUsers":null, //If null, allow all users,

Comment: If you could update your main post with this, unfortunately I'm unable to read this.